# Deploying MongoDB replica sets on two physical machines(in LAN).How to configure ACL ,network parameters and firewalls?

Tags: mongodb

Unable to add a replica set to the primary node. It is saying "not all the replica sets responded affirmatively and something..........". This could be something related to Access Control List , Network or Firewall.Please Help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately the question posted here is "off-topic" for this site as StackOverflow is a site dedicated to programming questions. Your question is about server configuration, and as such should be asked on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) instead. Please remove and repost your question on the correct site for your topic.